# MySQL select name from multi tables

Tags: mysql

I know it’s must be simple, but now I’m noob in sql, so for me it not simple.
I have 2 tables:

**ClassA**

```
Id     Name
1      Kate
2      John
```

**Class B**

```
Id     Name
1      Mark
2      Lisa
```

All names in tables ClassA and ClassB is unique.

So I need to INSERT INTO table **ClassB** name “Kate”, but before that I check if Kate already exist in tables ClassA and ClassB.

If exist, then return line from table, if not exist then return nothing

If for checking I use one table result is ok:

```
SELECT ClassA.name FROM ClassA WHERE ClassA.name=‘Kate’
```

Result:

*Name*

Kate

But if I check in two tables, result return nothing. I think it’s happened because ClassA return Kate, but ClassB return Null result

```
 SELECT ClassA.name, ClassB.name FROM ClassA,ClassB WHERE ClassA.name=‘Kate’ OR ClassB.name= ‘Kate’
```

Please help to fix my problem

Comment: Are you looking to an _insert_ or a _select_ ?

Comment: I’m lookin for select

Comment: Simply: don't have two tables!!!! Fix your broken schema!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I check if Kate already exist in tables ClassA and ClassB. If exist, then return line from table, if not exist then return nothing

You can use `UNION`:

```
select *
from (
    select id, name from classA
    union select id, name from classB
) t
where name = 'Kate'
```

Or, if you want to know from in which table(s) the name was found:

```
select *
from (
    select id, name, 'classA' tab from classA
    union all select id, name, 'classB' from classB
) t
where name = 'Kate'
```

Note: if the name exists in both tables, the second query will produce two rows.

Comment: Plainly, the flaw in this problem - the elephant in the room, if you like - is a sub-optimal design. Surely the role of SO is to improve our collective knowledge and use of the various technologies within its remmit, not to provide 'sticking plaster' solutions to poorly formulated problems.